# Is FilterSendNetBufferLists handler a must for an NDIS filter to use NdisFSendNetBufferLists?

Tags: c, windows, driver, ndis

everyone, I am porting the WinPcap from NDIS6 protocol to NDIS6 filter. It is nearly finished, but I still have a bit of questions:

The comment of ndislwf said "A filter that doesn't provide a FilerSendNetBufferList handler can not originate a send on its own." Does it mean if I used the NdisFSendNetBufferLists function, I have to provide the FilerSendNetBufferList handler?  My driver will send self-constructed packets by NdisFSendNetBufferLists, but I don't want to filter other programs' sent packets.

The same as the FilterReturnNetBufferLists, it said "A filter that doesn't provide a FilterReturnNetBufferLists handler cannot originate a receive indication on its own.". What does "originate a receive indication" mean? NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists or NdisFReturnNetBufferLists or both? Also, for my driver, I only want to capture received packets instead of the returned packets. So if possible, I don't want to provide the FilterReturnNetBufferLists function for performance purpose.

Another ressembled case is FilterOidRequestComplete and NdisFOidRequest, in fact my filter driver only want to send Oid requests itself by NdisFOidRequest instead of filtering Oid requests sent by others. Can I leave the FilterOidRequest, FilterCancelOidRequest and FilterOidRequestComplete to NULL? Or which one is a must to use NdisFOidRequest?

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

### Send and Receive

A LWF can either be:

- completely excluded from the send path, unable to see other protocols' send traffic, and unable to send any of its own traffic; or
- integrated into the send path, able to see and filter other protocols' send and send-complete traffic, and able to inject its own traffic

It's an all-or-nothing model.  Since you want to send your own self-constructed packets, you *must* install a `FilterSendNetBufferLists` handler and a `FilterSendNetBufferListsComplete` handler.  If you're not interested in other protocols' traffic, then your send handler can be as simple as the sample's send handler — just dump everything into `NdisFSendNetBufferLists` without looking at it.

The `FilterSendNetBufferListsComplete` handler needs to be a little more careful.  Iterate over all the completed NBLs and pick out the ones that you sent.  You can identify the packets you sent by looking at `NET_BUFFER_LIST::SourceHandle`.  Remove those from the stream (possibly reusing them, or just `NdisFreeNetBufferList` them).  All the other packets then go up the stack via `NdisFSendNetBufferListsComplete`.

The above discussion also applies to the receive path.  The only difference between send and receive is that on the receive path, you must pay close attention to the [`NDIS_RECEIVE_FLAGS_RESOURCES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag.

### OID requests

Like the datapath, if you want to participate in OID requests at all (either filtering or issuing your own), you must be integrated into the entire OID stack.  That means that you provide `FilterOidRequest`, `FilterOidRequestComplete`, and `FilterCancelOidRequest` handlers.  You don't need to do anything special in these handlers beyond what the sample does, except again detecting OID requests that your filter originated in the oid-complete handler, and removing those from the stream (call `NdisFreeCloneOidRequest` on them).

### Performance

Do not worry about performance here.  The first step is to get it working.  Even though the sample filter inserts itself into the send, receive, and OID paths; it's almost impossible to come up with any sort of benchmark that can detect the presence of the sample filter.  It's extremely cheap to have do-nothing handlers in a filter.

If you feel very strongly about this, you *can* selectively remove your filter from the datapath with calls to `NdisFRestartFilter` and `NdisSetOptionalHandlers(NDIS_FILTER_PARTIAL_CHARACTERISTICS)`.  But I absolutely don't think you need the complexity.  If you're coming from an NDIS 5 protocol that was capturing in promiscuous mode, you've already gotten a big perf improvement by switching to the native networking data structures (NDIS_PACKET->NBL) and eliminating the loopback path.  You can leave additional fine-tuning to the next version.